# Lengthening a DataFrame based on stacking columns within it in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am looking for a function that achieves the following. It is best shown in an example. Consider:

```
pd.DataFrame([ [1, 2, 3 ], [4, 5, np.nan ]], columns=['x', 'y1', 'y2'])
```

which looks like:

```
   x  y1   y2
0  1   2  3
1  4   5  NaN
```

I would like to collapase the `y1` and `y2` columns, lengthening the DataFame where necessary, so that the output is:

```
   x  y
0  1   2  
1  1   3  
2  4   5
```

That is, one row for each combination between either `x` and `y1`,  or `x` and `y2`. I am looking for a function that does this relatively efficiently, as I have multiple `y`s and many rows.

Comment: What if one of `x` values is NaN?

Comment: @Kasramvd Interesting question, but in my application that does not occuer

Comment: I guess most natural would be to repeat the nan in the same fashion in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one based on NumPy, as you were looking for performance -

```
def gather_columns(df):
    col_mask = [i.startswith('y') for i in df.columns]
    ally_vals = df.iloc[:,col_mask].values
    y_valid_mask = ~np.isnan(ally_vals)

    reps = np.count_nonzero(y_valid_mask, axis=1)
    x_vals = np.repeat(df.x.values, reps)
    y_vals = ally_vals[y_valid_mask]
    return pd.DataFrame({'x':x_vals, 'y':y_vals})
```

Sample run -

```
In [78]: df #(added more cols for variety)
Out[78]: 
   x  y1   y2   y5   y7
0  1   2  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  4   5  NaN  6.0  7.0

In [79]: gather_columns(df)
Out[79]: 
   x    y
0  1  2.0
1  1  3.0
2  4  5.0
3  4  6.0
4  4  7.0
```

If the `y` columns are always starting from the second column onwards until the end, we can simply slice the dataframe and hence get further performance boost, like so -

```
def gather_columns_v2(df):
    ally_vals = df.iloc[:,1:].values
    y_valid_mask = ~np.isnan(ally_vals)

    reps = np.count_nonzero(y_valid_mask, axis=1)
    x_vals = np.repeat(df.x.values, reps)
    y_vals = ally_vals[y_valid_mask]
    return pd.DataFrame({'x':x_vals, 'y':y_vals})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get things done i.e

```
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('x').stack().reset_index(level=0).values,columns=['x','y'])

     x    y
0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  4.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeat all the items in first column based on counts of not null values in each row. Then simply create your final dataframe using the rest of not null values in other columns. You can use `DataFrame.count()` method to count not null values and `numpy.repeat()` to repeat an array based on a respective count array.

```
>>> rest = df.loc[:,'y1':]
>>> pd.DataFrame({'x': np.repeat(df['x'], rest.count(1)).values,
                  'y': rest.values[rest.notna()]})
```

Demo:

```
>>> df
    x   y1   y2   y3   y4
0   1  2.0  3.0  NaN  6.0
1   4  5.0  NaN  9.0  3.0
2  10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   9  NaN  NaN  6.0  NaN
4   7  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN

>>> rest = df.loc[:,'y1':]
>>> pd.DataFrame({'x': np.repeat(df['x'], rest.count(1)).values,
                  'y': rest.values[rest.notna()]})
   x    y
0  1  2.0
1  1  3.0
2  1  6.0
3  4  5.0
4  4  9.0
5  4  3.0
6  9  6.0
7  7  6.0
```